# Lattice Structure of system $H(z)=1+0.7z^{-1}+1.2z^{-2}-z^{-3}$

Tags: digital-filters

When solving
$$A_{m-1}(k) = \dfrac{A_m(k)-A_m(m)*A_m(m-k)}{1-A_m(m)^2}\,,$$
the $A_m(m)$ here is $A_3(3)=-1$, which results in infinity if put in above equation.

How to solve it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE. Please typeset your mathematical equations in LaTex/MathJax to make it easier for users to understand your question. Also, please elaborate on the problem when asking a question so that it's easier for us to help you!